# Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas' with angular12

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chart.js2

I have created angular 12 application and trying to include barchart with my application using '**ng2-charts and chart.js**'

I have imported **NgChartsModule** in both app.module.js and my component.module.js file. But, Still I am facing the below error

***" Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'"***

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
"chart.js": "^3.5.1",
"ng2-charts": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

}

**mycomponent.module.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataset, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'


@Component({
selector: 'app-expence-manipulation',
templateUrl: './expence-manipulation.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./expence-manipulation.component.css']
})
export class ExpenceManipulationComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
   responsive: true,
};
public barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', 
'2011', '2012'];
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartPlugins = [];

public barChartData: ChartDataset[] = [
{ data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
{ data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
];

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExpenceManipulationComponent } from './expence- 
manipulation/expence-manipulation.component';
import { ExpenceInclusionComponent } from './expence-inclusion/expence- 
inclusion.component';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
ExpenceManipulationComponent,
ExpenceInclusionComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
NgChartsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**myapp.component.html**

```
 <div style="display: block;">
            <canvas baseChart 
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType">
          </canvas>
        </div>
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: we need to use it as "type" instead of "chartType"

 <div style="display: block;">
            <canvas baseChart 
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [type]="barChartType">
          </canvas>
        </div>

Answer (score 6):

In your HTML template, you should replace `[chartType]="barChartType"` by `[type]="barChartType"`.

> For further information, please consult [Chart types](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts#chart-types) from `ng2-charts` documentation.

Answer (score 3):

We need to use **"type"** instead of "chartType".

The below code works

```
 <div style="display: block;">
        <canvas baseChart 
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        **[type]**="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

[details for the solution](https://openbase.com/js/ng2-charts)

Comment: Hi Raji, welcome to StackOverflow. As @uminder's answer helps you, you should upvote/accept his/her answer. Instead of writing another answer that is the same as him/her. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in this way:

```
[type]="'bar'"
```

Additionally, if the chart type is line:

```
[type]="'line'"
```

And so on.